# clicking on back image it takes me from activity 2 to activity 1

Tags: android, android-activity, back-button

implemented the back image which takes me from activity 2 to activity 1. But now when i touch the back button of the mobile it takes me from activity 1 to activity 2. i don't want this to happen how can i restrict this

```
//here is my code
//this the imageview onclick listener
  findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backToMenu();
            }
        });
    }

===========================================
//and this is the method


private void backToMenu()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,Menu.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
    }
```

Comment: Is the `Menu` Activity still in the back stack? How did you start the current `Activity` and what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is wrong, because you are creating a new Menu activity on top of the second activity. You need to simulate the back button pressed behaivour.

```
private void backToMenu()
{
    onBackPressed();
}
```